# Report the items in descending order in vb

Tags: vb.net

with below code I could retrieve all ModelView names, skip the 8 views and print other views using `lw.writeline("Views: " & vw.Name.ToString)`

But I want to print the other views in descending order.

**Current output:**

```
Views: gdfgfdg
Views: 15455
Views: NewView
```

**Desired output:**

```
Views: NewView
Views: gdfgfdg
Views: 15455
```

**Code:**

```
Dim theSession As Session = Session.GetSession()
Dim workPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Work
Dim lw As ListingWindow = theSession.ListingWindow

Dim displayPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Display
'Dim list As New List(Of String)

Dim ViewNames() As String
Dim views As ModelingViewCollection
views = workPart.ModelingViews

lw.open()
    For Each vw as ModelingView in views
       ' lw.writeline(temp.Name.ToString)
            Select Case vw.Name.ToString
                Case "Back"
                Case "Bottom" 
                Case "Front" 
                Case "Isometric" 
                Case "Left" 
                Case "Right" 
                Case "Top" 
                Case "Trimetric"
                Case Else
                    lw.writeline("Views: " & vw.Name.ToString) ''' Print deleted camera nodes
            End Select 
    Next       
lw.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each vw as ModelingView in views.OrderByDescending(Function(v) v.Name)
```

Presumably `Name` is type `String` so calling `ToString` on it would be pointless in that case.

EDIT:

If you need to get an `IEnumerable(Of T)` from an `IEnumerable`:

```
For Each vw in views.Cast(Of ModelingView)().OrderByDescending(Function(v) v.Name)
```

Comment: Getting error at above line `'OrderByDescending' is not a member of 'NXOpen.ModelingViewCollection'.`

Comment: `OrderByDescending` is a LINQ extension method and, like most such methods, can only be called on an object that implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  Most collections do these days but, if `ModelViewCollection` is old or just poorly implemented and only implements `IEnumerable` then you'll need to call `Cast(Of T)` to get an `IEnumerable(Of T)`.  I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: But now getting error `'Cast' is not a member of 'NXOpen.ModelingViewCollection'.` Or can we collect these names in a list and then print? The reference document is here: https://docs.plm.automation.siemens.com/data_services/resources/nx/10/nx_api/en_US/custom/nxopen_python_ref/NXOpen.ModelingViewCollection.html

Comment: Used line: `For Each vw as ModelingView in views.Cast(Of ModelingView)().OrderByDescending(Function(v) v.Name)`